# iPad: Split view Controller

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am creating split view based application for iPad.

I have 1) a root view controller 2) a detail view controller

It is like menu and submenu.

Here I am planning to do. I would like to have navigation in root view controller.

It is recomonded to use or not. If it is recomended how is it possible.

Comment: Do you mean like the mail app, where you can choose a path, like All Inboxes --> Message?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in the Detail View Controller for showing or not showing the popover Button. Possibly you could adapt that in the App Delegate for the whole Detail View Controller? Just go through the source code provided by Apple. It is all well commented.

Comment: You are answering 2 years old question. OP has probably find a solution already.... But next time it would be more helpful if pointed where exactly in the source such example can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking. If you're asking whether it's recommended to do it like how you describe, then yes, that's the most recommended way to do it.

Root view controller (the smaller left side menu) usually contains the navigation stuff, while the detail view controller (the bigger right side view) contains all the detailed stuff.

You might want to take a look here for a [How-To](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/UserInterface/UserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH3-SW8).

Other documents can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/ipad/sdk/index.html).